# Google authentication request URL breaking (Clientside auth)

Tags: javascript, client-side, google-authentication

I have a small piece of javascript code that has always been working in an angular application:

```
  async googleSignIn(redirectUrl, userId) {
    let clientID=encodeURIComponent('redacted');
    let redirectURI=encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl);
    let scope=encodeURIComponent('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')+"+"+encodeURIComponent('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events')
    let url  = 
     `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&
     client_id=${clientID}&
     redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&
     access_type=offline&
     prompt=consent&
     scope=${scope}&
     state=${userId}`;
    window.open(url,"_self");
}
```

Nothing has been changed, but now it no longer works, instead I get a 400 error with a missing parameter. Which one is missing changes everytime I load the link (clientId, scope, redirectURI -- it always says ONE of these is missing even though they are present).

I verified that everything is there by using a debugger and inspecting the variable. I even copied the contents of the variable, pasted it in a new tab and IT WORKED. I'm really stumped, please could someone help me see what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) will render string as you write them, including `newline`, `spaces`,... those newlines are the problem.
removing extra characters will solve the problem:

```
let url  = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${clientID}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&scope=${scope}&state=${userId}`;
```